# "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: admin" with sample_data.rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

I'm going through Michael Hartl's tutorial and have a sample_data.rake file. When I try to populate the database I get the "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: admin" error. I can fix it by adding ":admin" to "attr_accessible" in the "user.rb" file but then that enables anyone to hack their way into becoming an admin. How can I resolve this issue?

**sample_data.rake file**

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    admin = User.create!(name: "Example User",
                 email: "example@railstutorial.org",
                 password: "foobar",
                 password_confirmation: "foobar",
                 admin: true)
      name  = Faker::Name.name
      email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
      password  = "password"
      User.create!(name: name,
                   email: email,
                   password: password,
                   password_confirmation: password)
  end
end
```

**user.rb file**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end
end
```

Thanks for any help! I'm a complete beginner so please keep it simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do:

```
admin = User.new(...)
admin.admin = true
admin.save
```

This way you are responsible for setting the admin flag. You are not setting the admin flag throuth a params hash. However in your case, creating a user in a rake file is not dangerous. It could have been if done in a controller like this:

```
User.create(params[:user])
```

As @Edmund just said in the comment, adding `:admin` into the `attr_accessible` list just means you can do a `.create` with `:admin` as one of the options.

Comment: Agreed. Set the admin attribute individually. Adding :admin into the attr_accessible list just means you can do a `.create` with :admin as one of the options.